# Selecting multiple values from a single LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, select

I am having issues selecting multiple values from a LINQ query. I Can actually get the results I am looking for but it's not how I would like it..

This is my query.

```
var getMovie = from item in entList where item.EType() == 
"Movie" orderby item.Rating select new { item.Title, item.Rating };
```

This is the result I am getting.

```
{ Title = Terminator 2: Judgement Day, Rating = 1 }
```

I am displaying the results in a listbox like this

```
 foreach(var items in getMovie)
                {
                    Results.Items.Add(items);
                }
```

Is there a better way of going about this so I could just get the values, and without the braces so it would look something like this or something similar?

Terminator 2: Judgement / 1

Comment: how do you get it? where do you display it?

Comment: Your question is vague. What does "looking like this" mean?

Comment: What do you mean how do I get it? I am displaying it in a list box. I will edit my question.

Comment: As I stated, I basically just want the values them selves. I don't want it to say Title = sometitle. I just want the title. also, I don't want the curly braces around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a matter of *getting* the data, it's a matter for *presenting* it properly using your list box. Your current implementation uses the default `ToString`; you want a custom title, so you need to tell the list box how to get it.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
var getMovie = from item in entList
    where item.EType() == "Movie"
    orderby item.Rating select new {
        Id = item.Id
    ,   Display = item.Title + " / " + item.Rating
    };
```

Add these items to your list box the usual way, and set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` as follows:

```
Results.ValueMember = "Id";
Results.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri It's not necessary, concatenation operator `+` calls `ToString` automatically for you.

Comment: I don't have an "id".

Comment: @Kalkrin Pick some field to identify the movie when you get the data back from the list box. It could be a combination of a title and a year, or simply a title. Replace `Id = item.Id` with `Id = item.Title`.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* getting the values themselves. You are retrieving a sequence of anonymous type instances, generated by `new { item.Title, item.Rating }`. You can access those properties and format your objects however you like.

You have been confused by the built-in `ToString` for anonymous types which exists for debugging purposes.